# Smart Card always return 69 99 - Command not allowed

Tags: smartcard, gemalto

No matter what command (APDU) I use (even VERIFY), I get SW1=69 SW2=99 response!
I triend literaly everything (changing default PIN, adding certificate using Gemalto MiniDriver Manager)

Does anyone have any idea what to do?
As far, I only need simple thing - To write 2 bytes of data somewhere on card and later read them. I can't believe it is so complicated!

```
Info:
Reader Name: Gemplus USB Smart Card Reader 0
Card Name:   Axalto Cryptoflex .NET
Card ATR:    3B1696417374726964
```

Comment: Could you post log of your communication from the moment you insert the card into the reader?

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible reasons for the 6999 error. Here are 2 reasons I can think of:
1. CLA byte is wrong (specifically the logical channel)
2. the application is not yet selected (Select command was not yet performed)

There could be other reasons too of course. Posting your log would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you would be better off using a simple memory card or at least a card using an ISO 7816-4 file system. With a java card such as you seem to have you would need to write an applet understanding your read and write commands, download that to the card and finally send the commands implemented.

A card with a file system understands a set of commands like create file, update binary, read binary from the beginning and so reduces the complexity.

Update: The status 69 99 is not in the standard and since the values of SW2 are all marked as *reserved for future use* must be considered as non-compliant to it.